# How i can make this code in Java 8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is possible to do this in Lambda:

```
for (final WarehouseAddress address : warehouse.getAddresses()) {
    if (!Validator.isEmpty(address.getPositions())) {
        final Set<WarehouseAddressPosition> positions = new HashSet<WarehouseAddressPosition>(
                address.getPositions());
        if (address.getPositions().size() > positions.size()) {
            throw new FieldDuplicatedException("position error");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this without sucess:

```
final Set<WarehouseAddressPosition> positions = warehouse.getAddresses().stream().filter(a -> !Validator.isEmpty(a.getPositions())).collect(
            Collectors.toSet());
```

Because he try to collect a Set of WarehouseAdress instead of a Set of WarehouseAdressPosition.

> Error:(130, 156) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has
>   incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: br.com.erp.ejb.entity.sales.WarehouseAddressPosition
>       lower bounds: br.com.erp.ejb.entity.sales.WarehouseAddress

In Warehouse class I have:

```
private List<WarehouseAddress> addresses;
```

In WarehouseAddress class I have:

```
private List<WarehouseAddressPosition> positions;
```

Explanation:
This code gets the original list of positions and collects it in a Set, to make a collection without duplicated values and compare size with the original list, to check if it is duplicated. Because Set does not accept duplicated values the size will be different in this case.

Comment: What was the error message you were getting?

Comment: "Because he try to collect a Set instead of a Set."  No matter how many times I reread that, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the text now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to collect `WarehouseAddressPosition`, not `WarehouseAddress`, so you need :

```
final Set<WarehouseAddressPosition> positions = 
  warehouse.
  getAddresses().
  stream().
  filter(a -> !Validator.isEmpty(a.getPositions())).
  flatMap(a -> a.getPositions().stream()).
  collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you wish to fail the process when you encounter duplicate `WarehouseAddressPosition` in the same `WarehouseAddress`, I would suggest to change `private List<WarehouseAddressPosition> positions` to be a Set. This way you can find such duplicates before collecting the positions of all the addresses.

If you have a good reason not to make this change, you can make the same duplicate check (currently done in your original code) in the `filter` step (I hope I got the syntax right, since I have no way to check it right now) :

```
final Set<WarehouseAddressPosition> positions = 
  warehouse.
  getAddresses().
  stream().
  filter(a -> if (!Validator.isEmpty(a.getPositions())) {
                final Set<WarehouseAddressPosition> positions = new HashSet<WarehouseAddressPosition>(
                  a.getPositions());
                if (a.getPositions().size() > positions.size()) {
                  throw new FieldDuplicatedException("position error");
                } else {
                  return true;
                }
              } else {
                return false;
              }).
  flatMap(a -> a.getPositions().stream()).
  collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: does not work gives: Error:(136, 156) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      java.util.List<br.com.erp.ejb.entity.sales.WarehouseAddressPosition> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>)

Comment: @Claudinei Sorry, about that. I forgot to convert the list of positions to a stream. Try now.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. But there is another detail. I need to compare the size of two collections inside the loop, like I do in "if (address.getPositions().size() > positions.size())" part of my original code. Do you think this is possible with Lambda?

Comment: @Claudinei I'm not sure I'm following the purpose of this condition. Perhaps you can explain what you are trying to achieve. I must admit that your original code without lambdas confused me and my answer focused on fixing your lambda attempt. Why are you declaring the set inside the loop and overwrite it in each iteration? Aren't you trying to collect the WarehouseAddressPositions of all WarehouseAddresses?

Comment: yes but in original code in each loop interaction I compare the size of two collections, for checking if there is some duplicated position in List, because Set doesn't accept duplicated value so this collection will be smaller than the original. I edited the original question with more details, I'm very sorry for the poorly explained question.

Comment: @Claudinei What should happen if you find duplicates? I see you are throwing an exception in the original code. So, should the entire process fail in this case? What happens if there are duplicate positions that originate from different addresses? Do you need to identify those as well?

Comment: yes the entire process fails and a exception is thrown, I only need to know there is a duplicate position in the same address. Different addresses are not checked.

Comment: @Claudinei I updated my answer based on my understanding of your requirements.

Comment: [@Eran] This is correct now, but with the if statements i don't need to collect the list anymore, so I can remove the collect and flatMap parts if I want. Thanks and congratulations for the answer, I marked this as accept.